# ReactJs: Date().toLocaleTimeString not working

Tags: reactjs

Currently i am started learning ReactJs. I want to fetch the current time in react. But the method i am using shows some error. I want to fetch the current time.

I have tried some similar questions but it doesn't help me.

**what i have tried**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

let datte = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;

const Click = () => {




    return(
        <>
        <div className="container mt-5 text-center bg-danger rounded p-5 text-white">
            <h2>The current Time is : {datte} </h2>
            <button  className="btn btn-info btn-lg">Get time</button>
        </div>
        </>
    );
   
};

export default Click;
```

**The error i have got**

```
index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in h2 (at Click.jsx:13)
    in div (at Click.jsx:12)
    in Click (at src/index.js:7)
```

So how can i solve these errors..

Thankyou

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()`, you need to call that because [it's a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not  invoking the function. you are just saving it as a variable in datte . change the code like this

```
let datte = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this toLocaleTimeString();

Answer (score 0):

you do not invoke this right. the toLocaleTimeString is a function that gets one parameter like this :

```
// for specfic time
    let dateUS = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
//you can also leave it empty
let dateUS = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

[mdn doc for this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)